# How to define multiple relationships between two entities?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the scenario where a **user** can upload multiple **photos** (One-to-Many). The **user** also can have **a default photo** (One-to-One). However, I entity framework **core 2.0** tells that he cannot recognize the relationship when I use the following code:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Photo> Photos{ get; set; }

    public Photo DefaultPhoto { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DefaultPhoto")]
    public Guid DefaultPhotoId { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

How may I achieve these multiple relationships?

There error shown by EF-Core:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Photo.Owner' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

#### UPDATE:

Adding `[InverseProperty("Photos")]` to the navigation property **Owner** in File Model seems to be working. I am not sure if that is the correct way?

[image]
*In this image File=Photo; Uploader=Owner (to be comparable with the above model).*

#### UPDATE 2:

I confirm what @Ivan said in the comments, with DataAnnotation approach, I get One-to-Many in two directions instead of One-to-Many and One-to-One. This figure shows the generated database by using `InverseProperty` (the connection between the to entities show the bi-directional One-to-Many relationship):

[image]

*In this image File=Photo; Uploader=Owner (to be comparable with the above model).*

Comment: Add `[Required]` attribute to Photo > Owner and User > Default Photo

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado, why `required`? I do not want them as required. Maybe any reference to the documentation please?

Comment: Then you should make your foreign key nullable `public Guid? DefaultPhotoId { get; set; }`

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado, that did not work, I added the exact shown error to the question.

Comment: And what Owner represents?

Comment: @Evk, what do you mean? it is shown in the entity, it is a `User`.

Comment: Try to mark your `Photos` collection with `[InverseProperty("Owner")]` attribute.

Comment: I've just tested myself and adding `[InverseProperty("Owner")]` to `Photos` in your exact model (copy-pasted from question) does solve the issue for me (EF Core).

Comment: @Evk, sorry the error I commented above (I deleted it) was incorrect. I just get the same error shown in the question.

Comment: Well then I cannot help futher, because cannot reproduce (works for me). Maybe you can have some additional properties\models which you did not include in question?

Comment: @Evk, I do not think so, because the problem disappears when I comment out one of the two relationships with `Photo`. I will try a bit more, then I will create a new simple project and retry your solution, thank you!

Comment: If nothing helps - post full code (all models and DbContext) and specify EF core version too.

Comment: @Evk, I made an update, could you take a look?

Comment: Well after all `InverseProperty` solved the issue it seems?

Comment: @Evk, yes, your comment guided me to the solution thank you. You told me to mark the collection, which did not work (for me at least), but worked with `Owner`. I am still confused and not sure why it works. Could you please explain a little bit why did this work when I added this attribute to the `Owner` (and not to the Collection)? And how the relationships are now determined? I have the feeling that the relationships are somehow broken (despite it works now). Is that solution I provided stable and a correct solution?

Comment: This attribute tells which property from another class is "the other end" of navigation property. So by marking `Photos` with [InverseProperty("Owner")]` you tell that another end of navigation property Photos in class User is property `Owner` in class `Photo`. Same can be done in reverse. If you mark `Owner` with `[InverseProperty("Photos")]` - you are doing the same. Why it works one way and not the other for you - I'm not sure.

Comment: @Evk, sorry for bothering, I still have a related question, according to this model (and the photo I added). Isn't this considered a circular relationship (which is very bad)?

Comment: Well it's not very good indeed. For that to work, one of the columns should be nullable (either `UploaderId` or `ProfilePictureId`). I guess that's how it was generated (seems not visible from your screenshot). But that's the nature of your model (to set default photo you need to have photo id, and to insert photo you need to know user id).

Comment: @Evk, I checked that, actually both columns in the database are set to (NotNull). I have not tried adding data yet, just to generate the database by EF-Core. I guess this will throw an exception when I try to add some data. So I have to define one of them to be nullable explicitly right?

Comment: I guess so. When I generated database from model in your question - one of them (`OwnerId`) was declared as nullable. I wonder what would happen indeed when you try to insert into your current database.

Comment: `InverseProperty` solves just half of the problem - correctly relating one-to-many relationship defining navigation properties. However the second relationship by convention is one-to-many, not one-to-one as desired. Forget about data annotations, fluent configuration is a must.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I did not get exactly what you mean, could you show that please as a code or diagram?

Comment: Take it this way - by default the inverse of `Photo DefaultPhoto` in `User` is something like `ICollection<User> DefaultPhotoUsers` in `Photo`, or in other words - one to many. There is no way to configure it as one to one using data annotations, hence you should use fluent API (as in @gldraphael answer).

Comment: @IvanStoev, so what Evk suggested gives me one-to-many relationship in two directions, rather than one-to-many and one-to-one?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @IvanStoev, thank you! That makes now sense. I updated the question to show that we really get bi-directional One-to-Many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Fluent API to establish the one-to-one relationship:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Establish a one to one relationship with the
    // User as the dependent End
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOne(u => u.DefaultPhoto)
        .WithOne(p => p.Owner)
        .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.DefaultPhotoId);
}
```

For a relationship to be a one-to-one (`1:0..1`) relationship, the relationship must be established between two primary keys or two candidate keys. (Check [this blog post](https://gldraphael.com/blog/notes-on-database-relationships/) for more info on this.)

EF has no way of setting a candidate key (also called unique or alternate key) via Annotations right now, so this is your only option. Check the EF docs here at Microsoft Docs: [One to One relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns)

---

**Update:** The earlier code would automatically generate a `UserId` column and sets up relationships correctly. I've added the `OwnerId` field to the `Photo` entity to manually set the relationship, like you wanted:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Owner")]
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos{ get; set; }

    public Photo DefaultPhoto { get; set; }
    public Guid DefaultPhotoId { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // You may use this instead of the inverse property
        // // The One to Many relationship between
        // // User.Id (Principal End) and Photo.OwnerId
        // modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>()
        //     .HasOne(p => p.Owner)
        //     .WithMany(u => u.Photos)
        //     .HasForeignKey(p => p.OwnerId);

        // Establishes 1:0..1 relationship between
        // Photo.Id (Principal End) and User.DefaultPhoto (Dependent end)
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(u => u.DefaultPhoto)
            .WithOne() // we leave this empty because it doesn't correspond to a navigation property in the Photos table
            .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.DefaultPhotoId);
    }
}
```

The trick is in figuring the relationships (especially the principal end and the dependent ends) and in figuring which ones require navigation properties.

The Inverse property is required because EF doesn't know which property to map to `Photo.Owner`. It's just a way of making a relationship explicit in cases like these.

Comment: I am trying this, but what if I added `public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }` to file entity? (I have tried adding it but no success, even the key is defined).

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin managed to get it working or do you want me to update the answer?

Comment: with a help from Evk I got it working, but **I still do not understand why** it is working. You can update the answer, so you share the knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I've made an update. Let me know if you have questions. This was a major source of frustration when I got started with EF. But once you get this, it's a piece of cake.

Comment: Thank you! Will the first piece of code do both One-to-Many and One-to-One relationships? I do not understand exactly how will it do that.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin the one to many relationship is established by EF conventions in the first instance. That code is just for the 1:0..1 relationship. Whenever EF can't figure things out it'll throw an error, which is why you saw the error in the question in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160856/discussion-between-gldraphael-and-mohammed-noureldin).

Comment: I have one further related question. Is `InversePropery` usable for Collections? or can we use it in One-to-One relationship? I mean if we have 2 or more One-to-One relationship in between 2 entities

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I'm not sure. Haven't tried that, and can't think of a use-case either.

Comment: A use-case is, for example, two One-to-One relationships between two entities.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin why would you need that is what I'm asking. Because you'll either end up with a redundant `1:1` relationship, or a `1:n` (in disguise?).