# How to allow cascade delete for complex object that has two lists of other complex objects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling with trying to make it work.

I'd want to have an `Dealer` who has Two Lists of the same type of `Items` that are in relation, but I'd want also to be able to cascadly delete them.

```
public class Dealer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Car> OldCars { get; set; } = new List<Car>();

    public List<Car> NewCars { get; set; } = new List<Car>();
}

public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
}
```

What I've been trying:

**Attempt #1**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
.HasOne(s => s.Dealer)
.WithMany(s => s.OldCars)
.HasForeignKey(x => x.Dealer)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
.HasOne(s => s.Dealer)
.WithMany(s => s.NewCars)
.HasForeignKey(x => x.Dealer)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

---

> System.InvalidOperationException: ''Dealer' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Car' because it is configured as a navigation.'

**Attempt #2**
Meanwhile with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
.HasOne(s => s.Dealer)
.WithMany(s => s.NewCars)
.HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id) <--- Principal!
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

It works properly, but shows warning that

> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model[10605]
>         There are multiple relationships between 'Car' and 'Dealer' without configured foreign key properties causing EF to create shadow properties on 'Car' with names dependent on the discovery order.

[image: Data in db]

Unfortunely while attempting to perform Delete (cascade) it throws an exception:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Cars_Dealers_DealerId1". The conflict occurred in database "testDB", table "dbo.Cars", column 'DealerId1'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

**Attempt #3**

When I add Dealer's Id to Car

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public Dealer Dealer { get; set; }

    public Guid DealerID { get; set; }
}
```

It yells about

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot create, drop, enable, or disable more than one constraint, column, index, or trigger named 'FK_Cars_Dealers_DealerId' in this context. Duplicate names are not allowed.
>   Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'DealerId' in table 'Cars' is specified more than once.'

**#Attempt #3.1**

So, after renaming `Guid DealerID` to e.g `Guid DealerID123`

it yells

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Cars_Dealers_DealerID123". The conflict occurred in database "testDB", table "dbo.Dealers", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Anybody has an idea how to make it work?

Comment: You need to override the behavior and add foreign key with fluent api like '.HasOn() and .WithMany()'.

Comment: Check this how to implement multiple relationship https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728331/how-to-define-multiple-relationships-between-two-entities

Comment: Such design introduces *multiple cascade paths* problem which does not allow cascade delete. You'd better avoid it by providing single collection (relationship) `Cars` and add `IsOld` or similar property to the `Car` model. Once you have all cars, you can always emulate your current collections with simple LINQ.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Dealer` and `Car`? Based on `Dealer`, it will have many `Cars`. Will one `Car` only belong one `Dealer`, or one `Car` could be different `Dealers` even be the one `Dealer` with `OldCar` and `NewCar`. You need to recheck your business. Or, you could try define the database firest, and then try to generate the model code.

Comment: I'm interested on that question too, did you find an answer to that ?

Comment: @cydef I used soft delete / manual delete

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ivan Stoev recommendation, I managed to resolve it as follow:

```
public class Dealer
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public List<Car> OldCars { get; set; } => NewCars.Where(c => c.IsOld == true);
   public List<Car> NewCars { get; set; } = new List<Car>();
}

public class Car
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Model { get; set; }
   public Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
   public bool IsOld { get; set; }
}
```

In EF6 ModelBuilder I did as follow:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>()
.HasMany(d => d.NewCars)
.WithRequired()
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```